# Double nginxes in AWS EC2 give me somebody IP else

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2

**Background:**
I have AWS EC2 with Elastic IP. And my EC2 has host-nginx in order to deal with `ssl` certificate without touching the `docker containers`

And in my `docker environment` I have `nginx, django, ...etc`
`nginx-container` serves `media/static_files`.

I am aware that `nginx` can customize `header`. Therefore I add prefix `http` in front of its name.

My `host-nginx` has complied with `http_realip_module`. Here is the output of `nginx -V`

```
# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3
built with OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

**host-nginx.conf:**

```
#
# UAT let everything serve through 8000. Development server
#
upstream app {
    server localhost:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name poink-dev.mycompany.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name poink-dev.mycompany.com;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
    ssl_certificate /home/admin/chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/admin/wildcard.mycompany.com.key;
    real_ip_header      X-Forwarded-For;

    location / {
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;
            proxy_set_header           Host $host;
            proxy_pass                 http://app;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }

}
```

**contianer-nginx.conf:**

```
upstream app {
    server backend:8000;
}

server {
    listen       8000;
    server_name  localhost;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header           Host $host;
        proxy_pass                 http://app;
        proxy_set_header XX-Real-IP $http_x_real_ip;
        proxy_set_header XX-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /var/www/static/;
    }

    location /media {
        autoindex on;
        alias /var/www/media/;
    }
}
```

**permission.py**:

```
def is_facebook_ip(client_address: str):
    """
    This one is faster than lookup on my own database
    """
    obj = IPWhois(client_address)
    results = obj.lookup_whois()
    asn_description = results.get('asn_description')
    return 'facebook' in asn_description.lower()
```

**views.py**:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes(())
def read_header(request):
    remote_addr = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    http_x_real_ip = request.META.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP')
    http_xx_real_ip = request.META.get('HTTP_XX_REAL_IP')
    http_x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    http_xx_forwarded_for = request.META.get('XX_FORWARDED_FOR')

    data = {
        'remote_addr': remote_addr,
        'http_x_real_ip': http_x_real_ip,
        'http_xx_real_ip': http_xx_real_ip,
        'http_x_forwarded_for': http_x_forwarded_for,
        'http_xx_forwarded_for': http_xx_forwarded_for,
    }
    return Response(data=data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**Question:**

```
http_x_real_ip = request.META.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP')
```

Return me my company ISP gateway IP address. I am not sure enough that my code will get the Facebook IP addresses properly. Since my program show different IP from another myIP website

The answer from my website : `61.xxx.xxx.xxx`
The answer from others : `183.yyy.yyy.yyy`

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Setting X-Real-IP to simply be the $remote_addr is going to be prone to error. Generally you would use it along with the real_ip module in NGINX which is able to look at X-Forwarded-For for *trusted* source ips to walk back until it gets to an untrusted IP. So likely some sites are applying XFF and some aren't.

Comment: @JoshuaDeWald By that. How can I determine the Facehook's IP addresses? I have updated my question in order to show my `permission` on webhook api

Comment: I think you are going to want to look at what's in the `X-Forwarded-For` header and see the chain there and then look into the `real_ip` module for NGINX, which is going to get you closer to what you are trying to do I believe

Comment: @JoshuaDeWald I have updated my question according to your comment. Unfortunately, I still got the same IP address. I started to wonder about my ISP might has multiple international gateways.